# Gmail does not detect the reply-to field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, gmail, actionmailer

I have following settings in my **FeedbackMailer**.

```
def notification(feedback)

  from       "admin@gmail.com"
  subject    "Some feedback"
  recipients "admin@gmail.com"
  reply_to   feedback.creator.email
  body({ :feedback => feedback })
  content_type "text/html"
end
```

I am using *admin@gmail.com* account to send emails for this application. The emails are delivered perfectly. And when I check the *details* of the email after receiving it, I see following:

```
from     "admin@gmail.com"
reply-to "user_email@foo.com"
to       "admin@gmail.com"
```

Now when I press on the `reply` button in the gmail interface, the `to` field should now have the "user_email@foo.com" but it is having "admin@gmail.com". Am I doing something wrong or gmail is?

Comment: I have the exact same question. I am confused that Google Mail seems to support neither the From-field (it uses the user_name from the SMTP settings instead) nor the Reply-To header.

Comment: I asked the same question on google help centre. This is what I got: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=6f34c68f09d02737&hl=en

Comment: Is this Gmail in the web UI or Gmail in iGoogle form?  They handle Reply-To differently.

Comment: This is Gmail in web UI.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As the [thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=6f34c68f09d02737&hl=en) Waseem pointed out in a comment indicated.

> Gmail ignores the reply-to when the
>   From is one of your configured send-as
>   addresses in gmail. I don't know why.

I took this as a hint and replaced the *From* email field by the user_email@foo.com and added the same user_email@foo.com as a *Reply-to* address. Gmail now uses the Reply-to field correctly.

Comment: I do not recommend using your customer's email as the From email as it will receive a Phishing notice from Gmail and other email clients. Use something like "server@your-domain.com" for the From and the customer's email as the Reply-to.

Comment: I just tested the proposed answer here (replacing both, from and reply-to fields to be some_user@foo.com) and it didn't work: The reply-to field was indeed some_user@foo.com but when you hit reply in Gmail's web interface it completely ignores it and goes with the from, which they force on their end. It will *probably* work on a different email client but definitely not on Gmails's web UI. Annoying.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the raw headers of the email instead of just looking on the details, as it is possible that other header affecting the reply function were set by your email server - Sender header, for example. You can see the raw email code using "Show original" function, under the arrow icon in the top-right corner.

Comment: Please post comments as comment, not as answer :) Check the 'add comment' link below the question.

Comment: @BalusC: You need 50 reputation to comment on other people's questions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in gmail itself to allow you to change the reply to address.

I can't figure out a way to dynamically change the reply to address, but here's how you can do it if you need to send email from several addresses (such as shipping, orders, feedback) but have it reply to a separate account.

Here's how I have it set it up.

Email address ($50/year) :

```
 automated@example.com          (I use this account to send from in code)
 customerservice@example.com    (customer service logs into this account)
```

Aliases (free) :

```
 shipping@example.com
 mark@example.com
 orders@example.com
 feedback@example.com
```

All these aliases are configured to send mail to `automated@example.com` and they are put into labels there via filter rules.

I send out from shipping, orders, feedback but want any replies to come to customerservice.

Here's how I set it up :

- Log into gmail as `automated` - must be logged in directly as the user you're sending from
- Click the accounts tab
- Add each alias you want to send from with the `Add another email address you own` feature
- Log in to `customerservice` and approve all the requests that should have been sent to each alias.
- Log back in as `automated` and click `edit info` next to each email
- Here you can click `Specify a different "reply-to" address` and enter `customerservice@example.com` as the reply to address.

I have slightly more complex reasons that I won't go into here why I have things set up like this - but if you want to change the 'reply-to' address this is the only way I've found to do it. Aliases allow you to send from multiple addresses and set `reply-to` to whatever you want. unfortunately though I cannot find a way to do this in code