# adding replyto when sending email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I'm sending email with asp.net c#. everything work perfect except replyto. I'm setting replyto  and send the email to myself. in the email client (ie. gmail) the replyto is correct but the reply goes to the email sender not to the alternate replyto that I have assigned. this is my code:

```
public void SendEmail(string subject, string body, string to, string reply,string replytoname, int nameID)
{
    MailAddress Sender = new MailAddress("sender@mydomain.com", "sender name", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    MailAddress Receiver = new MailAddress(to);
    MailAddress Reply = new MailAddress(reply, replytoname, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(Sender, Receiver);
    msg.Subject = subject;
    msg.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    msg.ReplyTo = Reply;
    msg.Body = body;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.mydomain.com";
    smtp.Port = 25;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sender@mydomain.com", "password");
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
    smtp.Send(msg);
}
```

[image]

Comment: If GMail is showing the correct reply to address, but not using it, this sounds like a GMail problem.

Comment: @TimB I don't think so. I'm right and google is wrong?

Comment: Unlikely I know, but I can't think of any reason it would show the address, but not use it. Perhaps there is a GMail setting for which address to use?

Comment: @TimB yeah, just as you said, I think there is a setting that I'm missing, thats why I posted the question so that you guys may know what I'm missing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957965/gmail-does-not-detect-the-reply-to-field

Comment: this explains everything, but i wonder that if I change from will my hosting send the email? because I remember that It was written (in my hosting help) that it doesn't matter whether the email exists or not but the domain must be one of those which I own

Comment: for more on reply to in `asp.net` check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667006/asp-net-mail-add-replyto), hope helps someone.